# Extract week of year with components / set Monday as first weekday

Tags: objective-c, calendar, nsdatecomponents

I am developing an application, in which I repeatedly have to calculate in which week of the year a certain date is.

I know it sounds very simple. I would just use a date formatter if Sunday was not rated as next week, which annoys me.

So I decided to use date components. I have modified the calendar object, so the first weekday is Monday:

```
+ (NSInteger) getNumberOfWeekOfYearFromDate:(NSDate *)entryDate{

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [calendar setFirstWeekday: 2];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:entryDate];
    NSInteger weekOfYear = [components weekOfYear];

    return weekOfYear;
}
```

Unfortunately the return values are large numbers like "2147483647". What am I doing wrong? I did not find any solution when I was searching the web.

Cheers and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
+ (NSInteger) getNumberOfWeekOfYearFromDate:(NSDate *)entryDate{

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [calendar setFirstWeekday: 2];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:
        NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:entryDate];

    NSInteger weekOfYear = [components weekOfYear];


    return weekOfYear;
}
```